# Processing a tab-delimited file and storing fields in a complex data structure

Tags: perl

I am attempting to process the following file:

http://bioinfo.mc.vanderbilt.edu/TSGene/Human_716_TSGs.txt

...which consists of 700+ records with 11 tab separated fields per record. Each record consists of the same repeated categories, i.e., GeneID, Gene_symbol, Alias, Xref, Chromosome, Cytoband, Full_name, Gene_type, Description, Nucleotide_Sequence, and Protein_Sequence. I would like to extract all the GeneIDs (the first field in all records), all of the cytobands, and the all of the protein sequences and construct a complex data structure, e.g:

```
$genes->{$gene_name}{$cytoband} = $protein_sequence;
```

My issue is I have only been able to grab the first record (11 fields) and assign them to a list. I don't know how to capture and store all of the fields which comprise one column. My initial attempt is below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($gene, $symbol, $alias, $xref,
    $chromo, $cytoband, $full_name, $gene_type, $desc, $nuc_seq, $pro_seq);

open FH, '<', 'human_tsgs.txt';
    my @data = do {local $/; <FH>};
close FH;

for (@data)
{
    ($gene, $symbol, $alias, $xref, $chromo, $cytoband,
     $full_name, $gene_type, $desc, $nuc_seq, $pro_seq) = split "\t", $_;

     #print $gene, "\n";
}
```

Any constructive feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Caitlin

Comment: Well done on the pragmas btw! Unfortunately the modern approach does not seem to be that widely spread among bioperl people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you are reading the file. You are undefining `$/` by making it `local` in the block.

Here's what's happening because of that:

- If `$/`, which is [the input line seperator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), is `undef`, it will read the whole file as one line.
- Thus, `@data` will only have one element that contains the whole file.
- Later, when you iterate over it in your `for` loop, you get the whole file in `$_`.
- The `split` will give you all fields (although the 11th field should have `value_row1_11\nvalue_row2_1`.
- You have not seen that, though, because your debug only has `print $gene`, which is the first value.

---

What you need to do is read the file line by line. There's no need to meddle with `$/` for that.

```
open my $fh, '<', 'human_tsgs.txt' or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
  chomp $line;
  my ( $gene, $symbol, $alias, $xref, $chromo, $cytoband, $full_name,
       $gene_type, $desc, $nuc_seq, $pro_seq ) = split "\t", $line;
}
close $fh;
```

If you have larger files at some point, reading it line by line is also better for memory handling. If you slurp the whole file, you will need to store it in memory. This way, you only need to store one line at a time to process the data.

---

Another way to achieve this would be to use the [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV) module.

Comment: Hi. I like your answer but when I attempt to assign several of the fields to a complex data structure, I am seeing two separate errors: Can't use string ("1002") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at dash1.pl l line 19, <FH> line 1. When I use no strict 'refs', the previous error is eliminated but if I attempt to print with print $gene->{$gene}{$cytoband};, another error appears that says: Use of uninitialized value in print at line 22. Any ideas?

Comment: @CaitlinG I would need to see the exact code. Maybe you should post this as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
my @data = do {local $/; <FH>};
```

you need these lines:

```
my @data = <FH>;
chomp @data;
#now you have all lines in the @data array
```

Answer (score 1):

This program does what you want. I redirected the output of Data::Dumper to a text file, o33.txt.

I used the command line: **perl t9.pl Human_716_TSGs.txt > o33.txt**

(t9.pl is the program below)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;
use autodie;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ( { binary => 1, eol => "\n", sep_char => "\t" } );

my %genes;
while (my $row = $csv->getline (*ARGV)) {
    my ($gene, $cytoband, $protein_sequence) = @$row[0, 5, 10];
    next unless $gene =~ /^\d+$/; # eliminate header and final line
    $genes{$gene}{$cytoband} = $protein_sequence;
}

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%genes;
```

**Update:** Seeing how the geneid, (first field), is unique, (and you're sure they will be unique), you might want a different structure like:

```
$genes{$gene} = {cytoband => $cytoband,  protein_sequence => $protein_sequence};
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for the help. When I included the line my @ARGV='human_tsgs.txt';, the program hangs (apparently awaiting input). I'm using a WinXP machine with ActivePerl 5.16.3. Thanks.

Comment: @user1136670 I supplied the filename on the command line, not setting `@ARGV` in the program. Not sure why you couldn't but I guess you can't. Is it possible for you to supply the input filename on the command line?

Comment: @ user1136670 I just tried assigning the filename to `@ARGV` and it worked for me. Is your file in the same directory as your program? If not, you would neeed to prefix the path to your filename,

Comment: Hmm..this is perplexing. I 'commented out' the @ARGV line and used the example you posted earlier but the problem remains. If I press the return key, a blank line is inserted as if it is expecting further input. Thanks again for the help. I'll try to resolve this.

Comment: Ok. I solved the problem. I had manually removed the newline at the end of the input file. When I manually "unchomped it", the program produced the expected output ;)